# Filter multilevel array with multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to solve an issue where I have an multilevel array that needs to be filtered with user controlled filters.

Example of the array

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [objectID] => 5038
        [Data] => Array
            (
                [originalId] => 6

            )

        [titles] => InfoType Object
            (
                [_] => string
                [language] => eng
            )
)
```

The filters would be then language and objectID, for example.

Anything that doesn't meet the criteria will have to be excluded. Sounds perfectly find if that would be a SQL query, but it's not. The API returns a string that cannot be controlled and it's in a form of an array. Have to work with what you have.

The idea came up to write a function that would prepare an if-statement. Problem is that you can't do just that

```
   foreach ($cache as $listing) {
        foreach ($filters as $filter_param => $filter_value) {
            if ($query) $output[] = $listing;
        }
    }
```

In this case the $query would be equal to something like this:

```
$listing["titles"]["language"] =="eng" && $listing["objectID"] =="5038"
```

I'm pretty sure there's an easier way that wouldn't actually be bad. Really stuck with this one.

Comment: Filters come from a form. Whichever method suits you. So pretty much GET/POST.

Comment: I receive the filters in an associative way, so that is not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isGood($what, $filters) {
    foreach ($filters as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            if (isGood($what[$key], $value) === false) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            if ($what[$key] != $value) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

foreach($cache as $listing) {
    if (isGood($listing, $filters)) {
        $output[] = $listing;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats! That's a great solution that saves me one extra foreach!